# SSH: RemotePortForw. - Binding privileged port

Tags: ssh, remote, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

very short and basic question, i'm having trouble in a network's homework i'm having.
This is the point i'm asked to implement:

- Configure SSH remote port forwarding in order to
  redirect the port 83 of pc1 to the port 8000 of s1.

To do it, i used a simple

```
s1:~# ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -NR 83:127.0.0.1:8000 ssh_user@10.0.1.2 &
```

Where 10.0.1.2 is the ip of pc1, however every time i receive as return the warning:

*Warning: Remote Port Forwarding failed for listen port 83*

I have nothing running that's already using the 83, also if I try to locally (from pc1) try to listen on port 83 I can easly do it.

Note: i receive this error from all the  privileged ports i try to bind.

Comment: We ended up solving it with another tool with sudo to forward the privileged port. With ssh, forward a non-privileged port like 1443, then with socat do `sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:443,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:1443`

Answer (score 2):

You either need to be root to bind ports below 1024 or have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability. In order to obtain it run:

```
 sudo -E -- setpriv --inh-caps +net_bind_service --ambient-caps +net_bind_service --reuid $USERNAME /bin/bash
```

This runs as root the `setpriv` utility, which switches back to your `uid`, but adds the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root on pc1 aka 10.0.1.2 in order to redirect ports less that 1024, rather than ssh_user.

Since you can bind port 83 if you are logged onto pc1 (presumably as root), it might be easier to start from pc1 and ssh to s1. Use '-L' to bind port 83 locally rather than '-R'.

Comment: The user on s1 is root, on pc i tried to move ssh_user as a root user with :"usermod -aG sudo ssh_user" but nothing changed.

Yeah, it would be much easier to use a local port forw. but that's not what i'm requested to implement :c